# How I can dis allow user from selecting partial words from whole text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I want users to only be able to select the whole words from the given text not a partial one. But I am unable to get any solution for it.

Suppose Text is:

Hello! Nice to meet you

then, I want from UI user should not able to select "Ni" from "Nice" or something. They should only be allowed to select the "Nice" whole word from UI. Is that possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event

Comment: This website only has general info. My problem is different.

Comment: Please elaborate why you can't use an event listener for the `onselectionchange` event.

Comment: I am using that only to get the text and respective position but my problem is different. Can you please read my question again

Comment: I've reread it, and it seems like you want to modify the selection made by the user. Can you elaborate how your problem is different?

Comment: No, I want user should be able to select whole words from the the text not partial words.

Comment: Yes, you want to modify the selection. You can either select the whole words or clear the selection when it doesn't contain whole words.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, how I can do that?

Comment: Add an event listener for `selectionchange` and get the selection with `document.getSelection();`. Check if it's valid and modify it if necessary, e.g. a selection has a `setPosition` method and contains the content of the related HTML nodes. [onselectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectionchange) and [document.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection) contain more code snippets. You should also read [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)